# Writing a Python Script which uses pyWin32 in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, python, pip

I'm trying to make a Python script which runs in windows, but because of reasons I have to write it in Kali Linux.

Since it doen't exist on Linux, I can't add the additional libraries I need.

Should I give up and write it under Windows?

If I simply put in my imports and commands in my program, will they work when the script will be run in a Windows machine?

Comment: I do have to ask why you're attempting coding on Kali? It's a specialised distribution for designed penetration testing.

Answer (score 6):

You can’t install `pywin32` on Kali Linux because [it’s only available for Windows](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/#files). It provides access to the Win32 APIs and to COM objects, and a Python program intended to work on any Linux distribution shouldn’t need those (or it should only attempt to use them conditionally).

You could always try running Python under Wine but I suspect that would involve losing sight of what you were originally trying to do.